# Adding two integers in the debugger gives unexpected output

Tags: int, lldb, arithmetic-expressions

I feel silly asking this, but I've debugged this as far as I can.  I'm adding two integers together and am getting non-deterministic random letters as output.  Any idea what's going on?

[image][image]

Comment: Please post your code, not only pictures of it.

Comment: Well. Pictures of code would be better than pictures of the console :-)

Comment: The console shows that adding two ints doesn't give the expected output.  That's all that was needed to show that I should have been using e instead of po

Answer (score 1, accepted):

po stands for print object, so it may be creating a pointer. Try e instead: `e minutes * 60 + seconds`

Answer (score 0):

po by rights should just refuse to print anything that isn't an object pointer, but by popular demand we made it print the value of the expression's result if the expression didn't result in an object pointer.  I think people just got used to using "po" all the time...

That's somewhat convenient, but makes things confusing because if the number you wanted to "po" happened to also be an object pointer, then you would see the description of the object, not the number.

As long as the only objects were legit ObjC pointer values, this confusion was no big deal, 'cause pointers are in weird places in memory, and aren't numbers you would cons up in the ordinary course of things.  But a while back ObjC added "tagged pointers" - which are ObjectiveC objects whose contents (small strings, small integers, etc) will actually fit in a pointer..  They steal the low bits to make themselves look like an illegal pointer, then the rest of the number is the type & contents.  This is very cool for many reasons, but it makes this problem worse because now there is a much larger class of integers look like object instances.

The take-away is just as mackworth said above, don't use "po" to print things that aren't objects.